# Pur input radio in circle with CSS radio customizing

Tags: html, css, input, geometry

Good morning,
I would like to put input radio in this circle, and I found an answer working without this css, but I need to do that with this input radio customizing css, like here.

I hope you can help me.

The same things in table: why I can't put them in they?

Thanks!
Andrew

Here the css of radio:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1; }
  input[type="radio"] + label {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 2.825rem;
    padding-right: 0.875rem;
    position: relative; }
    input[type="radio"] + label:before {
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-transform: none !important; }
    input[type="radio"] + label:before {
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: solid 1px;
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      height: 1rem;
      left: 0;
      line-height: 1.86875rem;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      top: +0.25rem;
      /*top: -0.1625rem;*/
      width: 1rem; }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
  /*input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before*/ {
    content: '\f00c'; }

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  border-radius: 100%; }

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1.0; }

:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1.0; }

::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1.0; }

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1.0; }

label {
  color: #555555; }

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="url"],
select,
textarea {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
  input[type="text"]:focus,
  input[type="password"]:focus,
  input[type="email"]:focus,
  input[type="tel"]:focus,
  input[type="search"]:focus,
  input[type="url"]:focus,
  select:focus,
  textarea:focus {
    border-color: #ce1b28;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ce1b28; }

select {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cpath d='M9.4,12.3l10.4,10.4l10.4-10.4c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.4c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.4l3.3,3.3c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.9 c0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.4,0.9L20.7,31.9c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.4c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.9-0.4L4.3,17.3c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.4-0.9 c0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.4-0.9l3.3-3.3c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.4S9.1,12.1,9.4,12.3z' fill='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E"); }
  select option {
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #ffffff; }

input[type="checkbox"] + label,
input[type="radio"] + label {
  color: #444444; }
  input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
  input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #ce1b28;
  border-color: #ce1b28;
  color: #ffffff; }
input[type="radio"]:focus + label:before {
  border-color: #ce1b28;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ce1b28; }

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb !important; }

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb !important; }

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb !important; }

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb !important; }
```

Here old solution working with radio button without css:

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;position:relative">
     <label style="position:absolute;top:55px;left:0;right:0;margin:auto;width:100%;display:inline-block" align="center"><input type="radio"/></label>
  <svg height="334.4" width="334.4">
      <circle cx="167.2" cy="167.2" r="134" stroke="#00ffff" stroke-width=4 fill="#e6ffff" />
      <text text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1px" dy=".3em">
       <tspan x="50%" y="25%" dy="1.2em">Line 1</tspan>
   </text>
      <text text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5px" dy=".3em">
    <tspan x="50%" y="35%" dy="1.2em">Line 2</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="45%" dy="1.2em">Line 3</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="55%" dy="1.2em">Line 4</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="65%" dy="1.2em">Line 5</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="75%" dy="1.2em">Line 6</tspan>
   </text>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

[image: the example of unhidden radio. I would put only red.]

Comment: Your code is quite long and still we can't run the snippet because you only provided CSS. Try to provide the HTML also.

And what do you mean about tables ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I would like to put input radio in this circle"? Do you mean turn the circle itself into the radio or something else? Because the radio is already inside of the circle.

Comment: I found the method to put the radio button in circle, but only when the radio button is normal. If I change CSS radio "settings", the circle it does not contain anymore the radio button. Why?

Comment: I so would like to put the modified radio button in that code.

Comment: @AndreaP. Remove the `appearance: none`s from your `input[type="radio"]` and change `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`.

Comment: @user2796515 thanks for the support, but it doesn't still work. Strange.

Comment: @AndreaP. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5bm16nd/1/.  Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @user2796515 Ok thanks! I found now that the real input radio has been hidden, and put on another color.

Comment: @AndreaP. I added as an answer if useful.  Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
input[type="radio"] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
```

I keep the appearance removing the red button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `appearance: none`s from your `input[type="radio"]` and change `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`

See fiddle which shows the radio: https://jsfiddle.net/e5bm16nd/1/